# Selenium, PHPUnit: when I try get style attribute I get empty result instead of value

Tags: xpath, selenium, phpunit

I met a problem when I wanted to get style attribute of element.

```
$styleValue = $this->getAttribute("//ul@style");
```

But result of var_dump($styleValue) is

```
string(1) ";"
```

But I expected "margin-left: -2432px;"
So, where am I wrong? How can I get style attribute of element?

Comment: Do your `ul` elements all have the same style attribute?

Comment: it's only an example. I have another xpath that return only one ul element.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression is wrong. If you want to read the `@style` attribute of the `<ul/>` tag, you have to use two step expressions: stepping into the list, then into the attribute. Each must be seperated using a `/`, the `@` only denominates an attribute.

```
//ul/@style
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not an error description that helps. Read the [FAQ] and about how to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried this but have the same issue:  `string(1) ";"`

Comment: This still does not provide a sufficient error description (also the question posted above doesn't). Nobody will be able to help you as it is, without being able to reproduce the issue and/or knowing the input.